# Can D3.js visualizations be served using Hugo?

Tags: html, d3.js, hugo

I have some D3.js visualizations I want to server on a Github Pages website I made using Hugo. I'm struggling how to include the visualization (html and js file) within the markdown file.  Is this possible?  If not, can I just use a standalone html file on Hugo?

**Edit:**
I implemented the example @timur suggested but the plot still doesn't show.
[image: Resulting webpage]

Comment: Did you read the [documentation for hugo.js](https://gohugo.io/content-management/formats/)? Read also: [this thread](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/is-it-possible-to-insert-html-code-in-markdown-content/4867).

Comment: @Mehdi Going off the thread link: I tried adding a html file in my `/content/posts/` but it just rendered the html and javascript code, not the D3 visualization the html and javascript makes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's doable, as long as you can include javascript files for D3 itself and your chart definition:

Consider a slightly cut down version of [this example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-bar-chart):

#### /static/example.js

```js
margin = ({top: 20, right: 0, bottom: 30, left: 40})

height = 500
width = 500
data = [
  {name: "E", value: 0.12702},
  {name: "T", value: 0.09056},
  {name: "A", value: 0.08167},
  {name: "O", value: 0.07507},
  {name: "I", value: 0.06966},
  {name: "N", value: 0.06749},
  {name: "S", value: 0.06327},
  {name: "H", value: 0.06094},
  {name: "R", value: 0.05987},
  {name: "D", value: 0.04253},
  {name: "L", value: 0.04025},
  {name: "C", value: 0.02782},
  {name: "U", value: 0.02758},
  {name: "M", value: 0.02406},
  {name: "W", value: 0.0236},
  {name: "F", value: 0.02288},
  {name: "G", value: 0.02015},
  {name: "Y", value: 0.01974},
  {name: "P", value: 0.01929},
  {name: "B", value: 0.01492}
]

yAxis = g => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())

xAxis = g => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0))

y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)]).nice()
    .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])

x = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map(d => d.name))
    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
    .padding(0.1)

function zoom(svg) {
  const extent = [[margin.left, margin.top], [width - margin.right, height - margin.top]];

  svg.call(d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1, 8])
      .translateExtent(extent)
      .extent(extent)
      .on("zoom", zoomed));
  function zoomed() {
    x.range([margin.left, width - margin.right].map(d => d3.event.transform.applyX(d)));
    svg.selectAll(".bars rect").attr("x", d => x(d.name)).attr("width", x.bandwidth());
    svg.selectAll(".x-axis").call(xAxis);
  }
}

const svg = d3.select(".visualisation") 
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .call(zoom);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "bars")
      .attr("fill", "steelblue")
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .join("rect")
      .attr("x", d => x(d.name))
      .attr("y", d => y(d.value))
      .attr("height", d => y(0) - y(d.value))
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth());

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x-axis")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y-axis")
      .call(yAxis);
```

#### content/posts/my-first-post.md

```
---
title: "D3.js bars"
date: 2020-03-24T00:00:00Z
draft: false
---

### Hello
<div class="visualisation"> </div> <!-- Hugo supports html in markdown -->
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.15.0/d3.js"></script> <!-- load d3.js from CDN. you could potentially load it from /static folder as well-->
<script src = "/example.js"></script> <!-- this will pick our scipt up and render the chart -->
```

This structure might not be ideal as you could probably stick javascript references into reusable layout of some sort and potentially parametrise the chart definition so you didn't have to repeat it for every page. Without knowing your specifics it's however a bit hard to make these suggestions. I'm just hoping it gives you a good enough hint to keep going.

**UPD** I'm pretty sure the code itself is working: see [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v6pjfcze/). Hugo has different file layout, but point I'm trying to make here is it should all be a matter of ensuring both your javascript files get loaded.

**UPD2** starting version 0.60.0 Hugo [will not by default allow](https://gohugo.io/news/0.60.0-relnotes/) unsafe html content (such as  tags). To get it to work you need to enable it:

```yaml
markup:
  goldmark:
    renderer:
      unsafe: true
```

Comment: Thanks for getting me on the right track but this example doesn't seem to be working.  I even tried it on a local server without using hugo.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating a bit more? What sort of error error you get?

Comment: I don't get any error but "Hello" is the only thing that shows in the post.  I'm adding a screenshot of the result.

Comment: JavaScript seems to not have been loaded. Check out page source around `Hello`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by check out page source around hello?

Comment: I was suggesting to check out the rendered page source code and see if two javascript files: (`d3.js` and `example.js` ) are referenced.

Comment: I don't see either d3.js or example.js in the Inspector or Debugger tab.  That's where I would see them, right?  (I'm very ignorant to web development)

Comment: this is one place - you'd go there for debugging. I'm first suggesting to have a look at `Elements` tab and see what html around the `Hello` heading in your post looks like. Does it make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210274/discussion-between-qq3254-and-timur).